# SDL blitting is being really slow

Tags: c++, sdl

So here is my code problem:

I create a display screen:

```
displayScreen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
```

Then I create a background:

```
background = load_image("gliderGameBackground1.png");
// I optimize the image
```

Then I have an intermediate surface:

```
screen = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_SRCALPHA, 300, 300, 32,
                                   rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
```

Then I apply the surfaces:

```
apply_surface(0, 0, background, screen);
apply_surface(0, 0, screen, displayScreen);
```

The reason why I have an intermediate screen is my program is going to consistently make a 1920 x 1080 surface in a game loop then shrink it based on what the user wants and then display that surface. I have a netbook so I notice a drop in framerate pretty quickly and this drops it significantly. I plan on doing colorkey and per pixel alpha blitting as well as fullscreen in case that matters for flags.

So what am I doing wrong that is making this be slow?

Comment: Why scale it yourself?  Use an OpenGL surface and have it scale automatically.

Comment: Well I am not even scaling it yet, but I plan on using SDL_gfx zoomSurface()

Comment: Well, first off, you shouldn't need to create a new surface in each iteration of your game loop.  It would only make sense to create a new one if the window size changes.  However, if you use an OpenGL surface, you can avoid resizing SDL RGB surfaces and just change the OpenGL projection matrix when the screen changes size.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use [`SDL_DisplayFormat()`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdldisplayformat.html) to convert your surfaces to the display format for optimal blitting.